# How to get bigger font size in \documentclass{standalone}?

Tags: fontsize, standalone

The fontsize \Huge is small relatively to the image I am writting on. How can I increase the font size?

Comment: Please can you put a complete minimal example to see your problem?

Comment: For font size use for example `\fontsize{77}{84}\selectfont` ...

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

You need a scalable font, then simply set the `\fontsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{160}{200}\selectfont Enough?
\end{document}
```